# Two GridViews in one view

Tags: yii2

I developed a web site with Yii2 framework and I need some help. I need to show two different GridViews with different data in one of my pages. I managed to show the tables and their data, but when I switch from the page of one table to another, the pages the other tables change too.

How can I work on one table without get the others one involved? (I'm using [yii2-grid from Kartik-v](http://demos.krajee.com/grid))

```
<?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
  'filterModel'  => $searchModel1,
  'columns'      => $this->context->columnDefaultList($parm1),
]); ?>

<hr class="page_separator"/>

<?= GridView::widget([
 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider2,
 'filterModel'  => $searchModel2,
 'columns'      => $this->context->columnDefaultList($Parm2),
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configure You `Dataprovider` as

```
 $dataprovider1->pagination->pageParam = 'dp1';
 $dataprovider1->pagination->pageSizeParam = 'dp1-size';

 $dataprovider2->pagination->pageParam = 'dp2';
 $dataprovider2->pagination->pageSizeParam = 'dp2-size';
```