# two kartik\grid\GridView tables share same pagination get variable

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

i have two `kartik\grid\GridView` tables with pagination on same page. When I change page of first table, second table change its page too. They share same `$_GET` parameter `page` and `per-page`.

Any option to set pagination get variable names or any other way to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168203/two-gridviews-in-one-view/38168821#38168821

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `$pageParam` in `pagination` in your `ActiveDataProvider`:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
             'pageParam' => 'nameOfYourParam',
        ],
        'sort' => [
             'sortParam' => 'nameOfYourSortParam'
        ]
    ]);
```

Same for `$pageSizeParam` in `pagination`.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple grids on one page

Every Yii2 widget has so much encapsulated in it that using multiple GridView widgets is a simple activity that involves making few changes.

The only parameters indeed that are not customizable with the DataProvider model class are pageParam and sortParam, which define the current page index and the parameters used to order a grid.

Suppose, for example, that we have two GridViews filled with two different data providers, $firstDataProvider and $secondDataProvider.

In the controller, we will set the pageParam and sortParam parameters of each DataProvider:

```
 $firstDataProvider->pagination->pageParam = 'first-dp-page';
 $firstDataProvider->sort->sortParam = 'first-dp-sort';

 $secondDataProvider->pagination->pageParam = 'second-dp-page';
 $secondDataProvider->sort->sortParam = 'second-dp-sort';
```